# ListView selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

In a `ListView` control by default you select a row if you click on the content of a column but if you click on the row out of bounds of content then it wont select the row. Is there any quick way to do it expect specifying templates for each column?

I've tried (this actually works for ListBox ):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#01000000" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Isn't that style simple enough?

Comment: As mentioned - the style works for a List control but not for ListView. I'm looking for something similar for ListView or a different solution but not as time consuming as declaring templates for each column

Comment: There is no "List control"...

Comment: Could you post some code which demonstrates the issue? Using the default WPF themes i do not run into any problems, do you use a custom theme which breaks things?

Comment: Ah that may be it then, haven't checked the default WPF theme, I thought I'm looking at the default behaviour (like the ListBox). I'm using Catel as my Mvvm framework and it has a few themes bundled but those are the silverlight ported ones, haven't thought that may be the problem. Will check it out, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with ListView (did not test it with ListBox).  Hopefully this will apply.  I know this is not a tested answer but I cannot post code in a comment.  If it does not work please let me know and I will remove it.

```
    <ListView ... >
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
        ...
```